# jQuery Show/hide divs on click, target only children

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I need to show/hide divs on click, multiple times on the same page. Each button should affect its children only.

I can make it work for one container, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
    <a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
  </div>

  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});
```

But I can't for multiple container:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/7362/)

I know it sounds a stupid problem but I itried wrapping it in an `each()` function, or using `children()` but can't make it work. Thank you

NOTE: I can't add ids to containers as they're generated dynamically

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/XwN2L/7363/)**.

1. The `id` attribute should be unique in same document so you've to change your duplicate `id`s to classes.
2. Don't use attribute like `target` directly in tag please use `data-*` attributes, so your attribute should be `data-target`.

   **Example :**

   ```
   <div class="container">

       <div class="buttons">
           <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
           <a  class="showSingle" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
           <a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
           <a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
       </div>

       <div class="targetDiv div1">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
       <div class="targetDiv div2">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
       <div class="targetDiv div3">Lorum Ipsum3</div>

   </div>
   ```
3. Use `closest()` with `find()` to show/hide you divs and `.data()` to get the value from `data-*` attributes :

   ```
   jQuery(function(){
       jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
           var target = jQuery(this).data('target');
           var parent = jQuery(this).closest('.container');

           parent.find('.targetDiv').hide();
           parent.find('.div'+target).show();
       });
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `closest()` with `find()`

`closest()` will get nearest selector and then you can find the needed children for respected parent only.

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.container').find('.targetDiv').hide();
      $(this).closest('.container').find('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

FYI, it's not good practice to use same ID for multiple elements in DOM, use class instead of ID.

```js
jQuery(function(){
         jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
               jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
        });
        $('.showSingle').click(function(){
      
          $(this).closest('.container').find('.targetDiv').hide();
      $(this).closest('.container').find('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
  <a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
  </div>

  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
  <a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
  </div>

  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
       var target = jQuery(this).attr('target');
       var targetDiv = jQuery("#div"+target);
       jQuery(this).parents('.container').find('.targetDiv').hide(); 
       jQuery(this).parents('.container').find(targetDiv).show();
   });
});
```